# Simple countdown timer in loop?

Tags: jquery, loops, timer

I have a loop, which I'm calculating an estimated completion time for the user.

Basically, I would like the format to be `00:00:00 (hours, minutes,seconds)`.

I'm stuck on the seconds, I've been able to calculate how many minutes and seconds there are, however actually counting down I'm not so great at...

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZjWkb/

I know that my problem is that seconds is being displayed as 60, however it's not counting down because of the if statement, it just keeps setting it to 60 until it falls below 60.

What can I do to fix this?

I do NOT expect anyone to write the whole thing for me, I'm just stuck is all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the fiddle to include hours. Check now. I have edited your fiddle. Seems to work. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjWkb/7/

The issue was with below part:

```
var minute = (secondsRemaining) / 60;
secondsRemaining = secondsRemaining % 60;
```

Comment: Would you mind giving me a hint how I could get the hours to work?

Comment: You win at life sir. :)

Comment: there was a small bug. Timer went till 2 and then instead of 1, it went directly to "Finished". Updated code to fix this.

Comment: How do I set the count variable from a php variable without refreshing the whole page, just the section with a page section refresh call?

Comment: you can use ajax to get the count variable from php, and then start the timer

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 1500;
var callsPerSecond = 1;
var delay = 1000;

//count * delay equals 1500000 miliseconds
//1500000 miliseconds == 25 mins, no hours, yet hours are displaying?


function offsetLoop(i, counter, idsRemaining) {

    while (i < counter) {
        var minute = 0;
        var secondsRemaining = (idsRemaining * delay) / 1000;
        var leftSec = 0;
        var hours = 0;

        var remainder = secondsRemaining % 60;
        minute = parseInt(secondsRemaining / 60);


        if (minute > 60) {
        hours = minute % 60;
            minute = parseInt(minute / 60);
        }

        secondsRemaining = secondsRemaining - 1;
        leftSec = remainder;


        secondsRemaining - i;
        if (typeof minute == 'undefined') {
            minute = 0;
        }
        if (typeof hours == 'undefined') {
            minute = 0;
        }
        hours = addZero(hours);
        minute = addZero(minute);
        leftSec = addZero(leftSec);
        log(hours + ":" + minute + ':' + leftSec);
        i++;
        idsRemaining--;
        if (i % callsPerSecond == 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                offsetLoop(i, counter, idsRemaining);
            }, delay);
            break;
        }
    }
};

function addZero(num) {
    if (num < 10) {
        num = ('0' + num).slice(-2)
    }
    return num;
}

function log(text) {
    $('#log').html(text);
}

offsetLoop(0, count, count);
```

Comment: I'm actually wondering how I can implement the hours, would you mind explaining this please?

Comment: Thankyou! I have added in the 0 if the timer falls below 10 on any position, however, in the minutes section, why do seconds correctly count down to 0, then go to 59, but the minutes still stay at 60mins when it should say 59? http://jsfiddle.net/ZjWkb/3/